# не загружается картинка html spring

Tags: spring

Выводится ошибка:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

при попытке вывести картинку в html-файл на Спринге.

[image]

И вот ошибка в консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]